# There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

I have a report part which deployed perfectly every time I made any changes until today.

The report has around 20 links, and an image on it.

I have added a table to it today, clicked deploy and it gave me the following error:

```
Error   1   There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> Maximum request length exceeded.       0   0
```

As I say, all I have done is added a table to it and that has caused mayhem. WHY?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I faced this problem recently. There is a property called `maxRequestLength` which needs to be increased in the machine and `web.config` file which is in the following location.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer
```

Comment: For anyone using SQL 2017 Reporting Services (I guess this also holds for 2016) the web.config file now is in
*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server ReportingServices\MyReportserverInstance\ReportServer* folder.

Answer (score 6):

Late to the party, but I've seen this happen with reports that have multiple embedded images that you may have deleted from the layout but are still there under Report Data -> Images. They can balloon the size of the report, and it's easy to check before changing the max request length settings in IIS.

Comment: You might also find that you've embedded an image that's very high resolution (and overkill for your use case), in which case deleting the embedded high resolution image and embedding a lower resolution image could also work

Answer (score 5):

"SQL Reporting Services Error- Maximum request length exceeded"

This can be resolved by increasing the connection timeout property in web.config file in reporting server.
You’ve got to adjust the web.config for the web app, which in the case of reporting server, is usually somewhere like this:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\Reporting Services\ReportServer
Find the web.config file for your reporting services instance, open it up, and track down the line that looks something like this

```xml
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Now just add a max request length attribute in there to fix the problem, adjust your size as needed.  This is 5meg.

```
executionTimeout = "9000" maxRequestLength="500000" />
```

And now you’ll need to restart IIS.  start->run->"iisreset"

Ref:
https://www.isolutionspartners.com/2011/09/16/sql-reporting-services-error-maximum-request-length-exceeded/

Comment: your solution helped me. thank you! i could not find the property as it was using the default.
although, i think there is a typo in the value (missing a 0). this is 500KB